# Where to put composer in a CMS that is going to be used in other projects?

Tags: php, content-management-system, composer-php

Currently I am developing a small headless CMS. If anyone wants to use it he should just copy the root folder of my CMS and put it into his public_html folder. So for any requests to the CMS the URL looks like this:

example.com/my-cms-name/subfolder/...

To better organize third-party libraries I decided to use composer. But now I have the composer.json file and the vendor file in my CMS folder which is going to be in the public_html folder. So everything from composer will be available for everybody which is obviously not a good practice.

How can I overcome this problem? Should I do all composer things separately in a different folder? But then the user of my CMS has to include multiple folders into multiple directories which makes everything more complicated...

Comment: Why not put your application outside of the public html directory and then have some sort of routing setup? This is the better practice. 

If it's not a public file(s), then don't make them public. It's that simple ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree to Half Crazed. Probably people will have to upload your CMS files via FTP anyway and set a root path. So you might as well divide your scripts in private and public ones. So a directory structure like this might be a good idea.

```
-config
-public_html (root path that people must point their domain to)
 -css
 -javascript
 -images
 -index.php
 -.htaccess (optional)
-src (where your namespaced script should reside )
--MyApp
-vendor
-composer.json
-composer.lock
```

Update composer.json and add your own src, run update command. Then include the vendor autoload.php in your index.php and go the router/controller way.

Comment: Yes I will probably go for something like this. But I will put everything into just two folders (one outside/one inside of the public_html folder) to keep the installing easy. In the inside folder there will be just the routing index.php and js/css/Images. The rest (config, composer, vendor, ...) in the outside folder.

Comment: To give an example where someone did it different: https://github.com/directus/directus, they just put the composer things all in the public_html path if I understand them correctly.